# How to completely disable drag-and-drop of file in X11 Emacs?

Tags: linux, mouse, x11

This issue irks me for a long time... I use Emacs under X11 + KDE (`plasmashell` + `kwin_x11`), and Emacs GUI window always robs the dragging event when I am dragging a file from file manager into the other window. Is there any setting to ask Emacs stop capturing a dragging file outside Emacs, but still able to drag-and-drop mouse inside Emacs to select the text inside Emacs?

For example, when I want to drag a file into Firefox to upload it, if an Emacs window is on the way, Emacs will rob the dragged file and Firefox becomes unable to capture the event:

[image]

Found [GNU manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Drag-and-Drop.html) and [GNU Emacs Lisp Reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Drag-and-Drop.html#Drag-and-Drop), and I tried to `(setq dnd-protocol-alist nil)`, but seems useless.

BTW, I didn't try this under Wayland yet, don't sure if it will has the same issue. If Wayland also does, I want to disable this feature under Wayland as well.

Comment: Did you try other apps? For example, replace Emacs with an app which also receives dropped pictures. I guess this is your desktop window manager's problem instead of Emacs. The window manager should provide an isolated environment for windows belonging to separate apps.

Comment: @shynur I've used KDE Plasma + `kwin_x11` for about 10 years, I never encounter this issue on any other application, no matter it is written in Qt 4,5,6 or GTK 2,3. Emacs is the only app which has such strange behavior.